# If $P$,$Q$,$R$ are midpoints of $BX$,$BZ$,$AC$, prove $\triangle PQR$ is equilateral.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Equilateral triangles $BCX$, $CAY$ and $ABZ$ are constructed externally on the sides of $\triangle ABC$. If $P$, $Q$, $R$ are the midpoints of $BX$, $BZ$ and $AC$, prove that $\triangle PQR$ is equilateral.

My try -

I couldn't have made any progress in this question after spending an hour ... kindly provide me a hint to start.....

Sources - CTPCM

Comment: Please kindly provide a picture, this is the minimal effort for geometry problems of this kind, especially when there is no other step performed. Please also try to type the text of the problem using mathjax, it is easy, and it would be nice. Is this homework? Which is the source of the problem?

Comment: No it is not homework it is question from an Olympiad book ..

Comment: Sorry but I am new ...do not know how to use mathjax

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference - this is similar to tex / latex. For instance `$\Delta PQR$` would give $\Delta PQR$. Simply place every mathematical object between dollar signs. The preview will show if things are done right. Knowing tex / latex is a big advantage when the mathematical path is starting...

Comment: If nothing provide a verbal description of what could not progress in one hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algebraic proof:**

Solution using complex numbers. Let $a,b,c\in \Bbb C$ be the affixes  for the points $A,B,C$, and we will use the convention, that lower case letters denote the affix point of the corresponding upper case geometric point. We may and do assume $b=0$. 
Let $u=e^{i\pi/3}=\cos 60^\circ+i\sin 60^\circ=\frac 12(1+i\sqrt 3)$ be this primitive root of unity of order six, so the multilicaiton with $u$ is implementing geometrically the $60^\circ$-rotation centered in $B$. One computes easily $u^2=e^{2i\pi/3}=\frac 12(-1+i\sqrt 3)=u-1$, i.e. $u^2-u+1=0$, et caetera.
Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= ce^{-i\pi/3}\ ,& p &=\frac 12(b+x)=\frac 12x=\frac 12ce^{-i\pi/3}\ ,\\ 
z &= ae^{+i\pi/3}\ ,& q &=\frac 12(b+z)=\frac 12z=\frac 12ae^{+i\pi/3}\ ,\\
&& r&=\frac 12(a+c)\ ,\\
&&|p-q|&=\frac 12|ce^{-i\pi/3}-ae^{+i\pi/3}|=\frac 12|ae^{2i\pi/3}-c|=\frac 12|au^2-c|\ ,\\
&&|r-q|&=\frac 12|a(1-e^{i\pi/3})+c|=\frac 12|a(1-u)+c|=\frac 12|-au^2+c|\ ,\\
&&|r-p|&=\frac 12|a+(1-e^{-i\pi/3})c|=\frac 12|au^2+(u^2-u)c|=\frac 12|au^2-c|\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and we get $|p-q|=|q-r|=|r-p|$, so $\Delta PQR$ equilateral. Job done.

$\square$

---

*Bonus 1:* The proposition remains valid if the two triangles are constructed "inside" (not "outside"). Proof: Exchange $a\leftrightarrow c$.

---

*Bonus 2:* The center of $\Delta PQR$ is located in 
$$
\frac 13(p+q+r)
=\frac 16(a(1+u)+c(1-u))=
\frac {\sqrt 3}2\cdot \frac 13(b+av+c\bar v)\ .
$$
Above, the value of $(1+u)$ was calculate like 
$$(1+u)=1+\frac 12(1+i\sqrt 3)
=\frac 12(3+i\sqrt 3)
=\sqrt 3\cdot\frac 12(\sqrt 3+i)=\sqrt 3\cdot v\ ,$$
where $v=\cos 30^\circ+i\sin 30^\circ$ is a primitive root of order $12$ of unity.

This point is the following one.

- The point $av$ corresponds to a $+30^\circ$-rotation centered in $B$ applied on $A$. After multiplication with $\sqrt 3/2$, this gives the mid point of $AZ$.
- The point $c\bar v$ corresponds to a $-30^\circ$-rotation centered in $B$ applied on $C$. After multiplication with $\sqrt 3/2$, this gives the mid point of $CX$.
- Consider the above two points, together with $B$, they determine a triangle, take its centroid, let us denote it by $O$. Then $O$ is the center of $\Delta PQR$.
- The center $O$ can be alternatively constructed as follows. Let $X'$ be the (in)center of $\Delta BCX$, and let $Z'$ be the (in)center of $\Delta ABZ$. Then $O$ is the mid point of $X'Z'$.

---

*Bonus 3:* The synthetic solution can now be easily found, knowing that we have to do something with $au^2$ (and with c\bar u^2). (See the formulas for $|p-q|$, $|r-q|$, $|r-p|$.) We construct the point corresponding to $au^2$, this is $A'$, the reflection of $A$ w.r.t. the segment $BZ$ (or w.r.t. the point $Q$), and also construct the point corresponding to $c\bar u^2$, this is $C'$, the reflection of $C$ w.r.t. the segment $BX$ (or w.r.t. the point $P$.)

[image: Napoleon theorem and variations, dan_fulea, mathematics stackexchange, 3563161]

**Synthetic proof:**
A $60^\circ$-rotation around $B$ shows $\Delta ZBX\equiv \Delta A'BC$, which gives $ZX=A'C$, and passing to the corresponding parallel mid line in appropiate two triangles, 
$$
QP=QR\ .
$$
Similarly $PQ=PR$.

$\square$

Yes, this proof is shorter, explaining how to get it makes the story longer.

Comment: Thanks for writing..but is there a elementary proof using Euclidean geometry of this ?

Comment: Yes, look at the  synthetic proof above. It is simple, in fact the picture contains it.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for a hint.

Let $A=(0,0),\space B=(a,0),\space C=(b,c)$ (Where $a,b,c$ are not the sides of your triangle $\triangle ABC$ at starting point).

By property of equilateral triangles you have

(1) Point $X$ is located in the $BC$ side mediatrix at a distance of $\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}BC$.

(2) Similarly Point $Z$ is located in the $AB$ side mediatrix at a distance of $\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}AB$.

(3) Find the midpoints of $BX,\space BZ$ and $AC$.

(4) Verify the corresponding distances are equal.